# character set, not set correctly

Tags: mysql, innodb, character-set, encoding

I have two database with a table with `utf8` table, I wanted to change the encoding of a column, I used two scenarios but a problem happened to me. 
at first the table was like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `spool` (
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `xml` text  NOT NULL,
  `seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `seq` (`seq`),
  KEY `i_despool` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_spool_created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**First scenario**

in the first one I change the row encoding with bellow command :

```
ALTER TABLE spool MODIFY xml TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

and then I use `show create table spool;` like this one :

```
 CREATE TABLE `spool` (
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `xml` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `seq` (`seq`),
  KEY `i_despool` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_spool_created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**second scenario**

In the second table I first changed the table encoding and then I changed the `xml` column encoding like this :

```
ALTER TABLE spool 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and then I changed column encoding like below :

```
ALTER TABLE spool MODIFY xml TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

and then we can see table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `spool` (
  `username` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `xml` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `seq` (`seq`),
  KEY `i_despool` (`username`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30849368 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

as you can see in the second scenario in front of the "`xml` text" we don't see the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` and I think it causes error for me because when Ejabberd wants to insert a query in the second one I see bellow error but in the other table I don't have this error:

```
HY000Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8F\\xF0\\x9F...' for column 'xml' at row 1"
** Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_odbc,sql_query_t,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},{line,173}]},{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},{ejabberd_odbc,outer_transaction,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},{line,443}]},{ejabberd_odbc,run_sql_cmd,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},{line,380}]},{p1_fsm,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm.erl"},{line,582}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]
```

in the first scenario we don't see this error but in the second one the error exists. how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. It looks like in second scenario you firstly [convert default charset for table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> To change only the default character set for a table, use this
>   statement: `ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset_name;`

So then you try to `MODIFY` charset of your `xml` column. But database 
may think that this column is already in the desired charset (remember you already change default charset)

Try to use one query like this ([see the same page of mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE spool 
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

> To change the table default character set and all character columns
>   (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT) to a new character set, use a statement like
>   this: `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;`
>
> The statement also changes the collation of all character columns. If
>   you specify no COLLATE clause to indicate which collation to use, the
>   statement uses default collation for the character set. If this
>   collation is inappropriate for the intended table use (for example, if
>   it would change from a case-sensitive collation to a case-insensitive
>   collation), specify a collation explicitly.

Comment: Interesting tricky point I think we can count this issue as a bug, I added the solution in the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying (in both cases) that an `INSERT` of xml containing  was performed.  And that it worked in the first case, but gave an error in the second case?

Describe the client -- its connection parameters, etc.

In the first all went well.  I suspect it was correctly saying `SET NAMES utf8mb4` or the equivalent in the connection string.

But the second case seemed to have been made with `utf8`.

Or are you saying that  was in the table, and an `ALTER` elicited the error message?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**:

guys answered this issue but I add some points here too:

as guys said, when we set the default character set of the table like bellow:

```
ALTER TABLE spool
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and after we set the `xml` column character set like this :

```
ALTER TABLE spool MODIFY xml TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

MySQL thinks that the `xml` column character set has been set so any changes would not happen and the character set will be shown like :

```
  `xml` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

this cause some errors at insertion to the table because really `xml` character set has not been set, and I think this can be a bug. I rolled back the `spool` table default character set.

```
ALTER TABLE spool CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

This caused that `xml` character set is now corrrect :

```
show create table spool

CREATE TABLE `spool` (
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `xml` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `seq` (`seq`),
  KEY `i_despool` (`username`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32533032 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and I don't get the database Error from Ejabberd neither.